# What was the relation between the Jedi Order and other orders of the Force?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, the-force

In addition to the Jedi Order, there were also some other public organizations in the Galaxy during the waning days of the Republic, that were formed around the Force. And I say public meaning that the Jedi were aware of them; not like the Sith, of which they learned about only (too much) later. One example in Canon would be the Guardians of the Whills, in Legends there were even much more.

How did the Jedi see these other Force orders? Did they voluntarily let them exist? Did they constantly keep an eye on them? Did they actively control or even subjugate them? Or did they just let them be? Did they cooperate with them? Were they considered rivals?

If there is any information about the connection between the Jedi Order and the Guardians of the Whills prior to the formation of the Galactic Empire, as well as about the role of Jedha in that, it would be especially interesting. Of course, information about the Jedi's relationships with any other Force cult would be exciting to know, too. Canon or Legends.

Answer (score 1):

*The Jedi Path*, a de-fictionalized Jedi guide book from the Legends continuity, has several pages on the matter.

This passage should answer your question:

> The Jedi Order is not the only organization to study and follow the Force. Countless schools have arisen among cultures that have the perception to hear the Force's call—from the Followers of Palawa to the order of Dai Bendu and the Chatos Academy. While these are admirable efforts, it is our convention that Jedi Order is the ideal interpretation of the Force's will. By all means, entertain other perspectives on the Force—but remember that every effort must be taken to bring these beliefs under the guidance of the Jedi.

**TLDR:** The Jedi respected their independence, but encouraged them to convert.

Comment: *"The Jedi Path, a **de-fictionalized** Jedi guide book ..."* Are you saying the Jedi are no longer fiction? ;-)